# Is there anyway to make this code still print one word per line but without a for loop?

Tags: python

```
string = input("Enter your Sentence:")
text = string.split()
for words in text:
  print(words)
```

I want this code to still print one word per line but without using a for loop is that possible?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a for-loop? What is wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join`:

```
print('\n'.join(string.split()))
```

or, the `sep` keyword argument of `print`:

```
print(*string.split(), sep = '\n')
```